# Blue Imp Jquery File Upload for .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Is anyone using, or can help me out with the Blue Imp [Jquery-File-Upload] for .NET? The issue I am having, is that I needed it to display the files currently in the upload directory when the form loads. Now, that works fine and dandy. Sort of..  The problem is, that I cannot get it to display the file thumbnails for the files. When I add new files to be uploaded, the thumbnails are shown, but not after the upload occurs. So, when the form loads, and after the upload occurs, I cannot get the thumbnails to show. I current set the form action to my generic handler in .net If a post is occurring, it process the file upload, and if a get request is occurring "on form load" it gets the current files in the directory, and returns the json for them, and then renders the download template for the files. Has anyone used this tool in .NET, and have they gotten the download template to work, along with thumbnails? The documentation is well, all but there, for .NET. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best solution is to download and explore the example

[here](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/tree/master/Examples/Demos_by_bluimp)

Comment: Thanks. I have worked some of this out since I posted this, but was hoping one day someone would come along and point me to some good information on it. I ended up writing all custom handlers, but the last issue I have is getting the thumbnail plugin to work when I manually trigger the fileupload plugin, to populate all files allowed for download on form load.  Thanks, I will check this out.

Comment: Hi casey also check --      
https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/tree/master/Examples/_HowTos